# Implementing property access operator in pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm trying to implement a DSL for writing custom condition expressions, which include keywords for certain objects and properties on those. E.g.:

```
user.foo.bar or user.baz
```

`user` is a keyword which is substituted with the current user object. I've also implemented `or`, `and` and `not` operators just fine based on the [existing sample](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/simpleBool.py).

I have implemented property access like this:

```
from pyparsing import infixNotation, opAssoc, Keyword, Word, alphas

class User:
    pass

class PropertyAccess:
    def __init__(self, t):
        self.value = reduce(lambda o, p: getattr(o, p, None), t[0][0::2])

user = Keyword('user')
user.setParseAction(User)
identifier = Word(alphas + '_')
property_access_expr = infixNotation(user | identifier, [
    ('.', 2, opAssoc.LEFT, PropertyAccess)
])
```

While this works, it also allows expressions like `foo.bar`, which are nonsensical. A property access must start with one of the supported keywords like `user`, otherwise they should be invalid. How can I reimplement the grammar to restrict that?

Comment: I like the use of `reduce` to make successive calls to `getattr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making the task needlessly difficult by using `infixNotation`. `infixNotation` is useful for defining multiple different infix operators with different priorities (i.e. order of operations). But property access has only a single operator (`.`), and is easily implemented with `OneOrMore`:

```
property_access_expr = user + OneOrMore('.' + identifier)
property_access_expr.setParseAction(PropertyAccess)
```

Changing the grammar like this requires a minor modification of the `PropertyAccess` class. Previously the input was a nested list, but now it is a flat list. Consequently, we have to change `t[0][0::2]` to `t[0::2]`.

```
class PropertyAccess:
    def __init__(self, t):
        self.value = reduce(lambda o, p: getattr(o, p, None), t[0::2])
```

Now the grammar correctly parses only attribute access that starts with `user.`:

```
>>> property_access_expr.parseString('user.foo.bar')
([<__main__.PropertyAccess object at 0x0000000002DD4048>], {})
>>> property_access_expr.parseString('foo.bar')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected "user" (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
```

Comment: I was just putting pieces together based on the limited exposure I had to pyparsing so far, and `infixNotation` was the only hammer I really knew. ;) Thank you!

Comment: If you suppress the '.' characters (with something like `DOT = Suppress('.'); property_access_expr = user + OneOrMore(DOT + identifier)`, then you won't need the `::2` striding slice, since the dots will be suppressed from the parsed results.